# Multiple connection string with different users in my web.config?

Tags: sql-server, database, authentication, web

I have my web.config like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="myConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=PC1; 
                           Initial Catalog=BD1; 
                           Integrated Security=SSPI"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      <add name="myConnectionString2"
         connectionString="Data Source=PC2; 
                           Initial Catalog=BD2; 
                           Integrated Security=False;
                           User Id=usuario;
                           Password=pass"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I can connect to the first one, a database with my windows user auth, but i can not to the second one, a database with other windows user auth.

Error: Login failed for user 'usuario'.

I can run Sql Server as other user, and i can connect to the database.

[Picture how i run SQL server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPkUD.png)

Comment: Can you tell what is the error message  that is being displayed?

Comment: Error: Login failed for user 'usuario'.

Comment: Do you have login credentials to access the database? If yes, Remove the the integrated security. If not, Keep only the integrated security and remove the user id and password from the connection string.

Comment: The image shows that you access the SQL server with windows authentication. So you have to set integrated security to true. The user name and password is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for you help Vikram. So integrated security = true, but where i specify it's other windows user?